# Error in Office 2010 when deploying as part of .wim?

Tags: deployment, microsoft-office-2010, windows-pe, wim, imagex

We're deploying Windows onto PCs with a very simple VM image setup, capture, and deploy using WinPE and imagex to create a single .wim with no network dependencies or capabilities involved in the setup process aside from adding the PC to the domain using our naming convention. It's quite a humble and truly "thrown together" solution, but it works well enough for our purposes (despite demonstrated need for more attention paid, but I digress).

The only true issue I'm having with this is our Office 2010 install. I've installed Office, repaired it, and reinstalled it several times (all pre-sysprep, as it must be there before sysprep), but I always get this error pop-up on the first run of any Office application that reads:

"Microsoft Access 2010 requires Visual Basic for Applications. If you continue, Visual Basic for Applications will be installed."

The message specifies Access no matter which Office application runs. Even after this goes through, Outlook no longer recognizes and sets itself up with domain usernames. It must be done manually. However, it Office has a repair operation run before any Office application is launched, everything works perfectly and without error.

Given the rest of the machine works perfectly on deployment, I'm heavily leaning toward the sentiment that Office was never meant to be deployed via sysprep & image capture.

Is this true? More to the point, is there a way around this without spreading the system into MDT, SCCM, etc?

Comment: Are you installing Office in the image pre-sysprep? Or trying to deploy Office as WIM separate from your OS image WIM?

Comment: Office is installed pre-sysprep.

Comment: Based on your comment, I'll have to add: *"I'm heavily leaning toward the sentiment that Office was never meant to be deployed via sysprep & image capture."* This is incorrect.  We've been deploying Office 2010/2013 included in OS WIMs for years now without issue. We also script the Office installation for the initial OS image creation. Something else is breaking in your environment. Need to find out what and where.

Comment: Are there known issues with starting from a basic Win7Pro-64 iso? All we're doing is using that, installing software from installers on network shares, configuring some OS options, and sysprepping.

Comment: No Office-specific issues I know of with that technique. We do roughly what you describe (software install from net shares, config OS, sysprep) with Win 7 Pro and Enterprise AMD64. No problems with Office 2010 ProPlus or 2013 so far. We did create an admin install point from the Office DVD ISO. We use admin install points whenever possible. There could be something else happening here... Can you verify your Office install media?

Comment: I actually never have verified it. We've been using the same installer off a share for years now. Considering we have no issues on normal installs even after years of use, I wouldn't imagine it's the installer. Adding to the confusion is the fact that a repair function fixes all issues after the image is deployed to a PC, which suggests the .msi Microsoft package part is solid... I'll go ahead and try to install it from a CD (or rather ISO) in the VM instead and see what happens on deployment Monday. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I had prepared my last image before leaving Friday and only tested the deployment Monday. I didn't expect much to change, but oddly... no Office errors. Normally, that would be fantastic news, but because of poor documentation on my part, I'm not sure what made the fix work. The last change I remember making is uninstalling Office and updating Windows, rebooting, and reinstalling Office. It seems this needs further looking at, largely due to personal error, but I won't be able to work on this again until this Friday...

Comment: If I find a major factor was the cause, I will report back on it. Otherwise I'm chalking it up to an undetected error during the installation of Office on the image.

Thank you for your comments jscott! I don't know why I hadn't thought of verifying the installation media before, but that advice may very well come in handy.